# No redirecciona a otra página

Tags: javascript, redirección

Tengo un documento HTML, el cual llama a un archivo JavaScript externo. En ese archivo JavaScript, en un momento dado intento redireccionar a otra página al cumplirse una condición, pero no redirecciona (he comprobado que la condición se cumpla, pues el alert dentro de la condición se ejecuta), de hecho parece que vaya a redireccionar pero es como si solamente refrescara la página.

He probado a hacer la redirección justo al empezar la función y la hace, pero la coloco donde tendría que estar y no lo hace.

También he probado de cambiar la redirección por un `window.open("ruta")` pero ocurre lo mismo, parece que la página refresque.

¿Qué estoy pasando por alto o que estoy haciendo mal ?

Dejo mi código JS:

```js
function sendForm(){
    //aqui SI funciona la redirección
    var fpU = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
    var fpP = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[1].value);
    var urlBase = 'http://xxxx,xx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.php';

    var sendJSON = {
        action: "login",
        fpU: "~C5B`/xs",
        fpP: "~C5B`Uú!a",
        browserInfo: {
            appCodeName: navigator.appCodeName,
            appName: navigator.appName,
            appVersion: navigator.appVersion,
            cookieEnabled: navigator.cookieEnabled,
            language: navigator.language,
            platform: navigator.platform,
            userAgent: navigator.userAgent
        },
        datasite: {
            "@accountID": "2",
            "@siteID": "3"
        }
    };

    var objJSON         = new Object();
    objJSON.sendJSON    = JSON.stringify(sendJSON);
    var responseGlobal;

    $.ajax({
        url: urlBase,
        data: objJSON,
        method: 'post',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            responseGlobal = response;

            if(responseGlobal.data == "ok") {
                alert("login correcto");
                //aqui NO funciona la redirección
                window.location.href = "front.html";
            }

        },

        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo por intentar, prueba con rutas absolutas:

1) `window.location.href = "/front.html";`

2) `window.location.href = "http://" + document.domain + "/front.html";`

Es algo raro tu caso, si se ejecuta el alert, debería funcionar la redirección.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, si que es raro si.

Comment: Intenta quitar el alert() a veces los alerts obstruyen la ejecución de código.

Comment: nada, pasa lo mismo, es como si se actualizara la misma página, el index

Comment: Hice una prueba por consola y si se refresco esta misma pagina, pero puse http:// y me llevo a la pagina que le dije, edite la respuesta.

Comment: @LuchoWeb es correcto, se redirecciona a URLs absolutas, por lo que convendría eliminar la primera opción, ¿no te parece?

Comment: A mi me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, añado el "http://" como en tu 2º opción, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo. Es como si fuera un refresh

Comment: A ti te funciona ?? por que a mi me sigue pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Holaaa buenas noches, a mi si me funciona el alert y el codigo solo es un un if

```
function sig(){
    if(document.elige.depto.value=="tecno"){
        alert("bienvenido");
        self.location="tecno.html"
    }
}
```

solo me muestra el alert pero nada mas